# How to get metrics of kong cluster behind load balancer

Tags: docker, kong

Currently, I'm using Kong API CE on my project, and use Prometheus plugin to get metrics.

But on production environment and autoscale, behind the load balancer, how can I get metrics for all kong instance from Prometheus server?

Should I use consul in this case? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Prometheus plugin**

- Install Prometheus
- Install Grafana
- Enable Prometheus Plugin in Kong
- Access Prometheus in your browser say at localhost:9090
- Access Grafana in your browser say at localhost:3000

Set Up Port Forwards:

If Kong proxy port is now your localhost 8000 port, Eg: If you are using plain-text HTTP proxy for this purpose

Create Some Traffic for the services and routes registered

Now Access Grafana Dashboard, you should be able to see metrics related to the traffic flowing through our services.